# Error with google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with the code below

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "Test extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "96": "icons/icon96.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
```

Keep getting this error from chrome "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 18, column: 6, Syntax error."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a final } character.

Put your code in JSON Lint and try it out (with and without the added closing bracket): http://jsonlint.com.